# 504 Gateway Timeout - Nginx

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx

I'm running PHP code on 'FPM application served by apache'. When I execute a mysql query which inserts 10,000 rows in the table I get this gateway error as

> 504 Gateway Timeout - Nginx.

Please suggest if I need to make changes in my.cnf or nginx.conf or httpd.conf and what kind of changes I need to make so that I can avoid this error ?

Comment: `nginx.conf` -> `keepalive_timeout 60;`

Comment: Its already set to 65. What else can be possible ?

Comment: Have you tried setting a larger timeout limit with [`set_timeout_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in php? [This](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/) is also a good read

Comment: No I have not tried that yet. What should be the value for this timeout then ?

Comment: Just give `set_time_limit(0);` a shot and see if that works. (*No time limit imposed*). ps, sorry was a typo - it's `set_time_limit();`

Comment: I have set max_execution_time = 60. Do you think it is good. It was set to 30 before.

Comment: Yeah I think it's good, but then debug from there because it seem's like your scripts are running out of time while processing.

Comment: So far it is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: no worries mate, glad it helped you!